# I can not get the log data with pexpect in multi ssh environment

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a switch and I can in it to show the configure with match:

```
admin@sele> show configuration | display set | match " ge-0/0/1 "   
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members vlan106
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching filter input Interface-Limit-100m
set class-of-service interfaces ge-0/0/1 shaping-rate 100m

{master:0}
admin@sele>
```

the config data is:

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members vlan106
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching filter input Interface-Limit-100m
set class-of-service interfaces ge-0/0/1 shaping-rate 100m
```

now I want to use `pexpect` to get the config data

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('ssh root@14.54.24.9')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('password')
child.expect('#')

child.sendline('ssh admin@10.10.10.1')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('my juniper switch password')
child.expect('>')

print('ldl1: ' ,child.before)
child.sendline('show configuration | display set | match " ge-0/0/1 "')
print('ldl2: ' ,child.before)
print('ldl2: ' ,child.after)
print('ldl2: ' ,child.buffer)
```

the log:

```
ldl1:  b'\r\n--- JUNOS 14.1X53-D47.3 built 2018-05-11 01:30:52 UTC\r\n{master:0}\r\nadmin@sele'
ldl2:  b'\r\n--- JUNOS 14.1X53-D47.3 built 2018-05-11 01:30:52 UTC\r\n{master:0}\r\nadmin@sele'
ldl2:  b'>'
ldl2:  b' '
```

there I can not get the config data.

---

**EDIT-01**

I use the time sleep 5 seconds, then it still the issue, there is no logs received by before or after.

```
import time
...
child.sendline('show configuration | display set | match " ge-0/0/1 "')
time.sleep(5)
print('ldl2: ' ,child.before)
print('ldl2: ' ,child.after)
print('ldl2: ' ,child.buffer)
```

Comment: Your shell example shows the device name as **s**ele in the prompt (`admin@sele`). The pexpect output says **d**ele (`admin@dele`). Are both from the same device?

Comment: same device, I changed the name.

Comment: Try expecting `>` after the second `sendline` call that invokes the command on the device shell. The prints in your code might happen before the child process received a result.

Comment: still not work, check my EDIT.